# itext7,html to pdf can not wrap long Engish words or long numbers

Tags: java, itext, itext7

When I transform html to pdf , I set enconding utf-8,when I convert pdf, long Engish words or long numbers can not wrap,but chinese can.

I am confused this problem several hours.

This is my html file:

> There are some chinese in html because is just a test. you can ignore it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>award system</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="part.css">
</head>
<body class="page-header-fixed">
<h2 class="part-title">七  Certificate Catalogue of Core intellectual     property</h2>      
<table style="table-layout:fixed;white-space:normal;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;" >
  <tbody>

      <tr >
        <td class="table-item" data-name="type">Invention Patent</td>
        <td class="table-item" data-name="name">一种访问网站的方法和系统</td>
        <td class="table-item" data-name="country">chinese</td>
        <td class="table-item" data-name="auth">ZL201310169965.9</td>
        <td class="table-item" data-name="date">2017-11-03</td>
        <td class="table-item" ><p style="white-space:normal;word-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-all;">2680796</p></td>
        <td class="table-item" data-name="obligee">www.ctbri.commmmmmmmmmmmmm</td>
        <td class="table-item" data-name="inventor">name</td>
        <td class="table-item" data-name="status">Authorized</td>
      </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is  css file

```css
body {
  background: none !important;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.part-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: none;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

table .item-name {
  width: 20%;
}

table .align-left {
  text-align: left;
}

table p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This is my java code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.media.MediaDeviceDescription;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.css.media.MediaType;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.WriterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontProvider;

public class Pdf0010HtmlToPdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // baseuri：the parent path of html/css/javasript
        String baseuri = "G:/TPractice/workOne/TransforePdf/src/main/resources/pdf0010htmlTopdf/";
        // html source file
        String desc = "G:/TPractice/workOne/TransforePdf/src/main/resources/pdf0010htmlTopdf/problem.pdf";
        File htmlSource = new File(baseuri + "problem.html");

        // pdfHTML specific code
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(desc);
            WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
            writerProperties.addXmpMetadata();


            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);

            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            pdf.setTagged();
            PageSize pageSize = new PageSize(575, 1500);
            pdf.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
            FontProvider font = new FontProvider();
            font.addStandardPdfFonts();
            font.addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\simhei.ttf");// set my font as chinese font 

            converterProperties.setFontProvider(font);
            converterProperties.setBaseUri(baseuri);
            MediaDeviceDescription mediaDeviceDescription = new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.SCREEN);
            converterProperties.setMediaDeviceDescription(mediaDeviceDescription);
            HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdf, converterProperties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("OK!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdf, converterProperties);//change this use below

    List<IElement> elements =HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), converterProperties);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
    document.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS,new DefaultSplitCharacters(){
        @Override
        public boolean isSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos) {
//return super.isSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos);//override this 
            return true;//解决word-break: break-all;不兼容的问题
        }
    });
    for (IElement element : elements) {
        document.add((IBlockElement)element);
    }
    document.close();
```